# Finding the resource from context menu selection - VS Code Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write an extension that adds an item to the context menu in the explorer.
Currently the explorer context menu shows my command, but I am unable to use the selected resource in the command.

I found this:

> *"When a command is invoked from a (context) menu, VS Code tries to infer the currently selected resource and passes that as a parameter when invoking the command. For instance, a menu item inside the Explorer is passed the URI of the selected resource and a menu item inside an editor is passed the URI of the document."*

Here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points

From an extension, I don't know what to call or if this can even be done?

...

Edit:

This question was marked similar to another. Doing what was done there logs nothing in my console.

```
let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('hellovscode.explorerOnclick', async (fileUri) =>{
    console.log(fileUri);
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable2);
```

No resolution yet.

Comment: create a command with an argument and set this as the command for the menu entry

Comment: @rioV8 I appreciate the response but, as this is my first time looking at VSCode extensions, I have no idea what you just said. I see that there has been a similar question asked so I'll check that out.

Comment: have you read the VSC doc about menu contribution? It is clear described what to do.

Comment: @rioV8 I have not. Could you please send me a link to this?